# What data structures can be used to represent multiple children in a tree in Python?

Tags: python, data-structures, tree

I want to represent data in this format:

```
                        Root

Block1         Block2              Block3 ....               BlockN
```

Each Block will have 4 children right now. I would want the ability to change this in the future so it should have at least 4 children and might have any more in the future.

```
                       Block

Child1    Child2                  Child3 Child4
```

Each child will have one floating value.
I want to know if any existing data structures exist for this in Python.

Comment: Pairing Heaps is a good way to go. Easy to implement in Python.

Comment: @SukritKalra: A heap would be entirely unsuitable for this purpose. The question isn't about ranking items or keeping track of the minimum item in a collection.

Comment: I assumed he wanted to do that, because he said the values would be floating values. Bad assumption, wouldn't nested lists be a better way to go then?

Comment: That's simple an `n`-ary tree. Use a `list` to represent the childrens, and if you want you can add some `property`s to access the first 4 children via attribute lookup.

Answer (score 0):

**defaultdict** maybe what you want

[here is the docs](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/collections.html?highlight=defaultdict#collections.defaultdict)

```
from collections import defaultdict
x = defaultdict(list)
x[some_block].append(some_child)  # add child
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data structure is essentially a two-dimensional array, where the first dimension is the block and the second dimension is the child.

In Python I'd probably use a list of lists:

```
child1, child2, child3, child4 = 1, 2, 3, 4
block1 = [child1, child2, child3, child4]
# other children, blocks, etc.
root = [block1, block2, block3, block4]
print(root[0][0] == 1)
```

If each child is just one value, you really don't need any more complexity than that.